# How to persist modifications to xinput

Tags: linux, xinput

Every time I reboot my Linux, I have to set the speed of my trackpad to 1.0 using the following command:

```
xinput set-prop 12 libinput Accel Speed 1.0
```

Is there a way to persist this change?

Answer (score 2):

You can add this to your `~/.xinitrc` (before the `exec` line starting your window manager).

If you don't have this file you can create it with `cp /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc ~/.xinitrc`

More information: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinit